# Why do I need enhancing data classes?

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, datanucleus

Sorry if this is kind of a noobie question.
I've been reading the google app engine getting started guide and I don't understand what this enhancing process does ? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview-dn2#Enhancing_Data_Classes 
 I tried to run without performing it and everything seems to work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Google page has links to all of the relevant places that explain it all, such as http://db.apache.org/jdo/enhancement.html

And no, if you don't do it then *everything will not be fine*.

Comment: Thank you, I've been using hibernate before. is It possible that this is done automatically with hibernate?

Comment: As one of those links says, Hibernate doesn't do bytecode enhancement and instead just uses some proxies, and consequently cannot detect what field has changed in an object without reloading it from the DB